# Преобразовать процедуру в подпрограмму

Tags: c#, сортировка, datagridview

Имеется вот такая процедура сортировки:

```
private void сортироватьЧастныеТаблицыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     dataGridView2.Sort(dataGridView2.Columns["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn8"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
```

Как можно преобразовать ее в подпрограмму и как ее потом правильно вызывать?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, как вы хотите ее использовать дальше. Если будете использовать ее дальше для сортировки разных dataGridView по разным dataGridViewTextBoxColumn, то можно вынести ее в отдельный метод и вызывать, передавая в него нужные параметры.

```
void SortDataViewByColumn(GridView dataGridView, string nameColumn)
{
    dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns[nameColumn], ListSortDirection.Descending);
}
```

Тогда для вашего примера:

```
private void сортироватьЧастныеТаблицыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView2, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn8");
}
```

Comment: Ругается, что не может найти тип или поле имен _GridView_.
Пробовал подключить _using System.Windows.Controls;_, но не получается с комментарием _директива using не нужна_

Comment: я написал образно GridView. Вам необходимо заменить на свой тип объекта, у которого имя dataGridView2.

Comment: Просто не знаю, какой объект вы используете.

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо большое